# Notes (Mac) can't connect to IMAP account, Mail can

Tags: macos, email, notes.app, imap

Lately when I try to use the Notes app on Mac OS X 10.8.5, I get a message saying "Notes can't connect to the account JW IMAP", and asking for my password.  If I enter the password, then a minute later the same error comes back.

I'm sure this has to do with the fact that my mail moved to a different server.  But where is Notes getting the old information?  If I choose the Accounts... menu item in Notes, it takes me to the Mail, Contacts, and Calendars pane in System Preferences, which currently has nothing in it.  If I click Add Other Account there, it takes me over to Mail, as if I were going to add a new Mail account.  But Mail is already correctly connecting to the new server, I don't want a new account there!

I tried repairing disk permissions and it didn't help.

I'm tempted to nuke the Notes files in `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes` and see if it gets reconstructed.

Comment: If you click Accounts in Notes, it opens the internet Accounts, like your emails, Twitter ect.. If you now click on one of the email accounts (assuming you have multiple) it will show you what is this account connected to. It should show Notes in that list, and it is either checked or not.

Comment: As I said, I have nothing in the accounts list.

Comment: I read that!! So you do not have ANY kind of Internet accounts what so ever on your system? hard to believe.

Comment: I don't have any accounts listed in the System Preferences "Mail, Contacts & Calendars" pane.  I have several in Mail.app's account settings.

Comment: If you could log in as different user to test the Notes. If it works without problems restore your User permissions settings in Disk utility.

Comment: @Buscar웃, I'm not sure what you mean by "works without problems".  If I log into a new account and open Notes, then it shows no notes and is not connected to any IMAP account.

Comment: Your user account has a setting to look for the YW account in Notes. The new user account does not, it is just empty notes. To possibly correct the problem I would suggest to run the permissions repair in Disk utility or even the ACL user permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I seem to have fixed it myself.  In `~/Library/Containers`, I renamed the folder `com.apple.Notes`.  When I next opened Notes.app, it reconfigured itself, asked for access to some keychain items, and now it can communicate with my IMAP account.  Furthermore, the next time I went to **Mail, Contacts, & Calendars** in **System Preferences**, the list wasn't empty any more.

Comment: Does not work for me (macOS Sierra upgraded from Yosemite).

Answer (score 0):

Notes accounts are usually associated with email accounts like iCloud, gmail, yahoo etc.

if you have an iCloud/iTunes account, log in to it under System Preferences-->Internet Accounts

Click the checkbox next to notes.

Open Notes, then drag your old notes into the iCloud account on the left.

Comment: I've never had iCloud turned on, and I'd prefer not to.  I had been using notes when notes were part of Mail.app, and when I upgraded to Mountain Lion, the notes went into Notes.app, so I never had to configure Notes.

Comment: Do you have any "Internet Accounts" configured in Sytem Preferences?

Comment: No, the "Mail, Contacts & Calendars" pane in System Preferences is empty.

Comment: do you have an account listed on the top left sidebar, ala "On My Mac"?

Comment: do you mean the sidebar of Notes?  There's an account "JW IMAP", which is the one it asks for a password for.

Comment: try turning off your wifi and then creating a new note... it may create an On My Mac account, which you could move your notes to.

Comment: Turning off wifi did not make On My Mac appear; Notes appeared the same except for "Offline" in the title bar.  Anyway, I don't want notes just on my Mac, I want notes on IMAP so they can be shared with my iPad, without using iCloud.

Comment: what client are you using for IMAP?

Comment: The IMAP client would be Mail.app for most of it, except Notes.app for the Notes folder.

Comment: what mail service are you using in Mail.app?

Comment: The mail server is at the company (pair.com) that hosts my web site.